# Djonog: storing an ArrayField gives an ambiguous error 'django.db.utils.DatabaseError'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I'm trying to store an `ArrayField` in a Django model called `User`, I'm using MongoDB and Djongo.

I managed to do it with one model called `Pair`, I can store a list of `Pair`s  and store that list in a `User` model using `ArrayField` which was fairly simple, I just followed [this example](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/#example) from Djongo's official doc

Now I'm trying to store another list but for some reason, it just keeps giving me a huge TraceBack (90 lines) with an ambiguous error: 'django.db.utils.DatabaseError'

here's my user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=127, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Active')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Admin')
    
    pairs = models.ArrayField (
        model_container=Pair,
        null=True
    )

    conversations = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Conversation,
        null=True
        )
```

again, the pairs attribute is working just fine but the conversation is not

The `Pair` model

```
class Pair(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Purchase price', max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        abstract=True
```

The `Conversation` model

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and this is the traceback:

```
        Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, tracker
Running migrations:
Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "accounts_user" ADD COLUMN "conversations" array NULL
  Applying accounts.0003_user_conversations...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 783, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 875, in parse
    raise e
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 856, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 888, in _alter
    query = AlterQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 425, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 435, in parse
    self._add(statement)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 598, in _add
    raise SQLDecodeError(err_key=tok.value,
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

    Keyword: array
    Sub SQL: ALTER TABLE "accounts_user" ADD COLUMN "conversations" array NULL
    FAILED SQL: ('ALTER TABLE "accounts_user" ADD COLUMN "conversations" array NULL',)
    Params: ([],)
    Version: 1.3.4

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 110, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 480, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/akram/Desktop/cointracker/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

Note: when I run `python manage.py migrate`, migrations are created with no problem, but when I apply them, I get the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

turned out that there's a problem with Djonogo specifically in this file djongo/sql2mongo/query.py

this question has already been answered in this [comment](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/505#issuecomment-757345199) on the djongo Github page